# how to pick date and time in WPF/c#

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm new to WPF, i want to implement UI to select both date and time from the user at a time, How can achieve this?

I tried with below code -

```
 <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Date, StringFormat='dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'}"/>
```

Not able to achieve, kindly requesting you to help me out?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Use the extended [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker) . The `DatePicker` control does not deal with time, only dates. So you will need to use a different control.
Install [Extended WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker) via `NuGet` packages in your project. and the use it like default DatePicker. But this has some extra properties, mentioned here [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/DateTimePicker). use them according to your requirement.

Comment: i cant use this control directly, can you post code snip here?

Comment: @lifeistoprogram i have update my Answer. Hope it helps :)